# I have a JButton inside of a JFrame that needs to call a method from a JPanel also in the JFrame. How can I do this?

Tags: graphics, oop, java

Basically, I'm handling JButton events inside ButtonHandler, which is a nested class inside a JFrame class called DrawFrame. When run, a JButton is placed within the JFrame alongside a JPanel class called DrawPanel. I need the button to call methods from the JPanel when pushed. I am currently getting a nullPointerException from panel.clearLastDrawing() and panel.clearDrawing(). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
public class DrawFrame extends JFrame {

    public static DrawPanel panel;

    public DrawFrame(){
        BorderLayout borderLayout = new BorderLayout();
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(borderLayout);

        JButton undoShape = new JButton("Undo");
        JButton clearAllShapes = new JButton("Clear");
        /*JComboBox colorSelect = new JComboBox();
        JComboBox shapeSelect = new JComboBox();
        JCheckBox shapeFilled = new JCheckBox();*/
        JLabel mouseCoords = new JLabel();

        panel = new DrawPanel(mouseCoords);
        JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel();
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(upperPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        upperPanel.setLayout(flowLayout);
        upperPanel.add(undoShape);
        upperPanel.add(clearAllShapes);

        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        undoShape.addActionListener(handler);
        clearAllShapes.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 if(e.getActionCommand() == "Clear"){
                    panel.clearDrawing();   //is panel not instancianted yet??
                 }
                 else if(e.getActionCommand() == "Undo"){
                    panel.clearLastShape();
                 }
            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: Pass the panel as argument to the ButtonHandler constructor.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually tried this before and didn't think it worked, but it was actually a problem with my DrawPanel's methods. Once I saw your comment I tried it again and found the actual problem. I appreciate it!